# Display Customer Attribute (Drop-down) in Admin Email

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, customer, email-templates, customer-attribute

My site has a customer registration page and Magento sends an email to the admin of the submitted registration form. However, there are 3 customer attributes that use a dropdown to enter information, for example Country, Business size, and Industry. Currently the email displays numbers and not the drop-down selection. Please view screenshot below.

How can we have Magento send the selected choice from the dropdown. My current code is below for the 3 drop-down questions on the registration form.

```
Country:        {{htmlescape var=$customer.country}} 
Business Size:  {{htmlescape var=$customer.customer_type}} 
Industry:       {{htmlescape var=$customer.industry}}
```

[image]
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Hi, can anyone help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The functionality of templates is not big enough to achieve what you want.

Instead you can include a block like:

```
{block type="your/type" template="your/template/for/email.phtml" customer=$customer}
```

Then you can implement the logic in the block and use the customer as data source